# How to remove the nested input object in the Graphene Django mutation query (Relay)?

Tags: graphql, graphene-python, mutation, graphene-django

I want to create a Mutation in Relay. I'm using **InputObjectType** pattern to separate the input and make it reusable.
In mutation class I'm using **Input** class and there I'm passing the InputObjectType

In general it works but the final query at the client side is very ugly.
I need to pass arguments in this way

```
query( input : { input : { ...arguments  } } )
```

and to be honest I don't like it. I think it looks ugly.

So the question is: *Is it possible to avoid to use a lot of these **input** objects?*
It's ok to use 1 **input** object, but the nested one is redundant and I'd like to avoid to use it.

Thanks for any help!

Here is the example

```
class FuelTypeInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    id = graphene.Int()
    label = graphene.String()
class FuelSubtypeInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    id = graphene.ID()
    label = graphene.String()
    fuel_type = graphene.Field(FuelTypeInput)


class CreateFuelSubType(relay.ClientIDMutation):
  class Input:
    input = FuelSubtypeInput(required=True)

  fuel_subtype = Field(FuelSubTypeNode)
  ok = graphene.Boolean()

  def mutate_and_get_payload(root, info, input):
    label = input.label
    fuel_type = FuelType.objects.get(pk=input.fuel_type.id)

    fuel_subtype = FuelSubType(label=label, fuel_type=fuel_type)
    ok = True
    return CreateFuelSubType(fuel_subtype=fuel_subtype, ok=ok)
```

The mutation query is:

```
mutation MyMutations {
    createFuelSubtype( input: { input : { label: "Mutation Subtype", fuelType: {
      id: 3
    }} } ) {
        fuelSubtype {
            label
        }
        ok
    }
}
```

It works fine, here is the result. But I'd like to remove the nested **input** things

```
{
  "data": {
    "createFuelSubtype": {
      "fuelSubtype": {
        "label": "Mutation Subtype"
      },
      "ok": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can fix with this:

```
class FuelTypeInput(graphene.AbstractType):
    id = graphene.Int()
    label = graphene.String()

class CreateFuelSubType(relay.ClientIDMutation):
    Input = FuelSubtypeInput

    fuel_subtype = Field(FuelSubTypeNode)
    ok = graphene.Boolean()

    # Other Code ...
```